# In php-mysql, How can I union the results of the sql query in a cell of the result table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making the code of PHP-MySQL. But I gain have the 2 and more as the result of the left join in the MySQL. So I want to union the results in a cell of the result table as the captured picture.

[image]

Here is my real captured picture in my computer.

My php code is as like below.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 { 

 echo "<table border='1' style='background:#dddddd;border-color:green;'>";
 echo "<h2><p >진료과 (Subject) : ".$row['subject']."</p></h2>";
   echo "<tr>";

 echo "<th >"."<form action='search1.php' method='get'>"."<button type='submit' 

  name='code' value='".$row['code']."'>Code</th>";
  echo "<th ><a href='".$row['ds_url']."'>"."한국병명</a></th>";
  echo "<th ><a href='".$row['ds_url']."'>"."Disease name(En.)</a></th>";
  echo "<th >"."<form action='search1.php' method='get'>"."<button type='submit' 

  name='code' value='".$row['family']."'>"." Family History</button> </th>";

 echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td >" . $row['code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td >" .$row['disease_co']."</td>";
  echo "<td >" .$row['disease_en']."</td>";
 echo "<td >" .$row['family']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  ---

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>소아과</th>";
  echo "<th>내과</th>";
  echo "<th>산과</th>";
  echo "<th>정형외과</th>";

   echo "</tr>";

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['ped_content']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['im_content']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['ob_content']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['os_content']."</td>";

   echo "</tr>";

   ----

  echo "</table>";
  }
```

The While phrase in the above php code is just 1, but the number of the result table depend on the number of im_content.

So, I want to union the result of im_content in a cell as the above captured picture. 
But, I am short of ability.
Please give me a piece of advice. 
Thank you for your concern.

My sql query sentence is as like below.

```
  SELECT code_en.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en , hx.family, 

  hx.personal, note.note, inclusion.inclusion, exclusion.exclusion, ds.ds_content, 

   ------

  subject.icd_category, subject.group_code, im.im_content
  FROM code_en
  LEFT JOIN subject ON code_en.code = subject.code
  LEFT JOIN note ON code_en.code = note.code
  -------
  left join im on code_en.code = im.code
  WHERE code_en.code = '".$code."'"
```

Thank you, Barmar!

Comment: `UNION` in MySQL means appending the results of two different subqueries. Do you mean _concatenate_? You want to combine `$row['im_content']` from different rows of the query results into one row of the table? Maybe you should use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in your query.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. But I have never heard GROUP_CONCAT(), Frankly I saw that the first time.

Comment: It's in the MySQL documentation. I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, since you haven't shown your query.

Comment: It's hard for me to figure out what you're doing, since I don't know Korean.

Comment: SELECT code_en.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en , hx.family, 
 -----, im.im_content
FROM code_en
LEFT JOIN subject ON code_en.code = subject.code
LEFT JOIN note ON code_en.code = note.code
LEFT JOIN advertiser ON code_en.code = advertiser.code
LEFT JOIN hx ON code_en.code = hx.code
LEFT JOIN exclusion ON code_en.code = exclusion.code
LEFT JOIN ds ON code_en.code = ds.code
LEFT JOIN sx ON code_en.code = sx.code
LEFT JOIN images ON code_en.code = images.code
-----
left join im on code_en.code = im.code
WHERE code_en.code = '".$code."'"

Comment: That's unreadable. Please put it in your question so you can format it nicely.

Comment: Above code is my sql query code. According to YOUR saying, I have to change my sql code that has im_content of the left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand the question, but I think this is what you want:

```
  SELECT code_en.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en , hx.family, 

  hx.personal, note.note, inclusion.inclusion, exclusion.exclusion, ds.ds_content, 

   ------

  subject.icd_category, subject.group_code, GROUP_CONCAT(im.im_content) AS im_content
  FROM code_en
  LEFT JOIN subject ON code_en.code = subject.code
  LEFT JOIN note ON code_en.code = note.code
  -------
  left join im on code_en.code = im.code
  WHERE code_en.code = '".$code."'"
```